# Error creating Transformer from CRS: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same celestial body

Tags: python-3.x, map-projections, proj

I am trying to create a transformation using [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/)'s CRS. I want to transform [map data](https://data.knmi.nl/datasets/rad_nl25_rac_mfbs_24h/2.0?bbox=53.7,7.4,50.6,3.2&dtend=2017-12-31T22:59Z&dtstart=2016-12-31T23:00Z&q=rainfall) (of the Netherlands) in [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) to a latitude longitude representation. I have found the necessary transformation info in the meta-data of the map, but I get the following error:

```
pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: Error creating Transformer from CRS.: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create_operations: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same celestial body)
```

I use the following python3 code to generate the transformator:

```
import h5py
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

with h5py.File(folder+filename, 'r') as f:
   proj4 = str(list(f['geographic/map_projection'].attrs.items())[2][1])
   proj4 = proj4[2:len(proj4)-1]
   from_proj = CRS.from_proj4(proj4)
   to_proj = CRS.from_proj4("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
   print(from_proj)
   print(to_proj)
   transform = Transformer.from_crs(from_proj, to_proj)
```

```
print(from_proj)
```

outputs:

```
+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0.0 +lat_ts=60.0 +a=6378.137 +b=6356.752 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +type=crs
```

```
print(to_proj)
```

outputs:

```
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +type=crs
```

```
transform = Transformer.from_crs(from_proj, to_proj)
```

generates an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_random_h5.py", line 100, in <module>
    load_random_h5()
  File "load_random_h5.py", line 50, in load_random_h5
    transform = Transformer.from_crs(from_proj, to_proj)
  File "/Users/user/miniconda2/envs/gdal_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/transformer.py", line 323, in from_crs
    area_of_interest=area_of_interest,
  File "pyproj/_transformer.pyx", line 311, in pyproj._transformer._Transformer.from_crs
pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: Error creating Transformer from CRS.: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create_operations: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same celestial body)
```

The problem might stem from the fact that the [map data](https://data.knmi.nl/datasets/rad_nl25_rac_mfbs_24h/2.0?bbox=53.7,7.4,50.6,3.2&dtend=2017-12-31T22:59Z&dtstart=2016-12-31T23:00Z&q=rainfall) represents precipitation (water falling in the atmosphere) about 1 km in the air, thereby not matching the radius of the earth, but this is just speculation. The [map data](https://data.knmi.nl/datasets/rad_nl25_rac_mfbs_24h/2.0?bbox=53.7,7.4,50.6,3.2&dtend=2017-12-31T22:59Z&dtstart=2016-12-31T23:00Z&q=rainfall) is a composite of two radar stations in the Netherlands. But I assume the projection information in the meta-data should be enough to apply a transform.

I have tried to replace the `from_proj` projection with several projections from the EPSG standard, but they all return nonsensical longitude latitude coordinates (sensical would be a latitude between 50 and 53, and a longitude between 3 and 8, in the case of the Netherlands). Concatinating the flags `+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0` to `proj4` negates the error, but again returns nonsensical longitude latitude coordinates.

Does anybody know a way around the error, or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the `a` and `b` parameters defined in your projection are in the incorrect units. They appear to be in kilometers when they need to be in meters.

When looking at the ellipsoid parameters of the `+proj=latlon`, you can see the magnitude of the ellipsoid is ~1000x that of the other projection:

```py
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> cc = CRS("+proj=longlat")
>>> cc.datum.ellipsoid.semi_major_metre
6378137.0
>>> cc.datum.ellipsoid.semi_minor_metre
6356752.314245179
>>> cp = CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0.0 +lat_ts=60.0 +a=6378.137 +b=6356.752 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +type=crs")
>>> cp.datum.ellipsoid.semi_major_metre
6378.137
>>> cp.datum.ellipsoid.semi_minor_metre
6356.752
```

Based on this, multiplying the `a` and `b` parameters by 1000 should fix your ellipsoid:

```py
>>> cp = CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0.0 +lat_ts=60.0 +a=6378137 +b=6356752 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +type=crs")
>>> cp.datum.ellipsoid.semi_major_metre
6378137.0
>>> cp.datum.ellipsoid.semi_minor_metre
6356752.0
```

And it does not have an error when creating the transformer:

```py
>>> from pyproj import Transformer
>>> trans = Transformer.from_crs("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0.0 +lat_ts=60.0 +a=6378137 +b=6356752 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +type=crs", "+proj=latlon")
>>> trans
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of unknown + Ballpark geographic offset from unknown to unknown
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
```